# Updating indices of models in a collection

Tags: backbone.js

I have a list of songs (each one in the form of an album cover) that are sortable via jQuery UI's sortable library (http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/). All of the songs are models that reside in a single collection. When a "sorted" event is fired, I want to recalculate the order of the songs and update their respective indices. I know how to get the index of a model within a collection, but is it possible to update/set a model's index? I realize that I can just set an "order" attribute on the model and update that, but it seems like updating the indices would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you will want to define a [comparator](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) on the collection, then call [sort](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sort) on it when the widget's sorted event is fired.

Comment: Took a second look at that function, and you're absolutely correct. Thanks :)